# React Native Android crash after importing Platform

Tags: android, react-native, crash, platform

My app was working without crash.

After I imported Platform from 'react-native' it suddenly crashes.

If I try to run the app, the emulator says `Unfortunately ... has stopped.`

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Animated, Platform } from 'react-native';
```

It worked before adding `Platform`.

Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it crash on an IOS emulator as well?
I've dealt with a problem like this before, and after I reopened the project in a new directory, magicly everything works perfectly.
one of many unexplained react-native bugs on Android.